# Как актуально отобразить результаты запроса на кастомный объект?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, symfony5, connection

Всем привет. Есть проект на симфони, сейчас там версия Symfony 5.2.
Открыл проект в PHPStorm и обратил внимание, что в методах, где идёт запрос в БД и отображение результата на объект, методы setFetchMode и fetch объявлены как Deprecated. Константа FetchMode::CUSTOM_OBJECT также объявлена устаревшей.
Как лучше всего переписать код в современных реалиях?

```
$stmt = $this->connection->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select(
        'id',
        'fname',
        'lname'
    )
    ->from('user_users')
    ->andWhere('email = :email')
    ->setParameter(':email', $email)
    ->execute();

$stmt->setFetchMode(FetchMode::CUSTOM_OBJECT, AuthView::class);
$result = $stmt->fetch();
return $result ?: null;
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, что лежит в AuthView? Возможно, вам стоит оформить соответствующую сущность, которая будет соответствовать таблице в базе данных, но однозначно ответить, на данный момент не могу. Посмотрите на уже решенный вопрос по этой теме: https://question-it.com/questions/2206453/kak-poluchit-rezultaty-v-nastraivaemyj-obekt-teper-kogda-fetchall-i-fetchmode-ustareli